# C++ openGl texture mapping images onto a sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, texture-mapping

hi i was just wondering how to render images (.cpp) onto a sphere on a cube in openGL im using Qtcreator so its C++ i have the coordinates im just at a loss how to put the image onto the actually sphere?

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand "onto a sphere on a cube"

I guess you meant "environment map"